# Botão de salvar pontos

Tags: javascript, html

Ola, preciso que alguem me diga como posso fazer um sistema de salvar meus pontos em java script, irei disponibilizar meu css html e javascript, aqui estão meus `codigos:`

```js
let add = document.getElementById('increment');

let int = document.getElementById('number');
let integer = 0;

add.addEventListener('click', function(){
    integer += 1;
    int.innerHTML = integer;
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nova+Square&display=swap');
body{
    background-color: #333232;
    font-family: 'Nova Square', cursive;
}
#container{
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 10px solid #926981;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background-color: #888169;
}**

h1{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

#number{
    height: 25px;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
}

#increment{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 190px;
}
```

```html
<h1>ClickxTraffic | Earn Clicking</h1>
<div id="container">
    <div id="number">0</div>
    <button id="increment">+</button>
</div>
```

Por favor preciso de ajuda.

Comment: Seu código está funcionando como esperado, ao clicar no botão "+" o número é incrementado e exibido. Defina melhor o que quer dizer em "salvar meus pontos".

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta reduzindo o problema a um [mcve]. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Comment: O que você quer dizer com salvar os seus pontos? E como utilizará o resultado desse salvar?

Comment: ola laercio, eu preciso de um codigo para quando a pessoa sair ou refrescar a pagina os pontos dela continuem

Comment: ola augusto, eu preciso de um codigo para quando a pessoa sair ou refrescar a pagina os pontos dela continuem

Comment: Porque não salva a pontuação no servidor, no banco de dados?

Comment: eu sou iniciante em html js e etc, eu não tenho isso

Comment: Você quer fazer um jogo sem o back end? Se salvar no navegador vai ter como trapacear o seu jogo.

Comment: como eu uso isso? por favor me diga

Comment: Para salvar no navegador use [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Exemplo: Para gravar `window.localStorage.setItem('Pontos', '1250');` para ler `window.localStorage.getItem('Pontos');`

Comment: poderia por favor me falar o codigo? eu preciso demais disso, crie o codigo, por favor eu preciso muito

Comment: O código é esse: `window.localStorage.setItem('Pontos', '1250');` que grava no registro `Pontos` o valor `1250` e quando quiser ler em uma variável `let p = window.localStorage.getItem('Pontos');` que coloca o valor do resgistro `Pontos` em `p`, ou seja `p` fica valendo `1250`.

Comment: irei testar e te digo

Comment: tentei assim e nao deu: let add = document.getElementById('increment');
let remove = document.getElementById('decrement')

let int = document.getElementById('number');
let integer = 0;

add.addEventListener('click', function(){
    integer += 1;
    int.innerHTML = integer;
})

window.localStorage.setItem('number', '10');
window.localStorage.getItem('number');

Comment: poderia colocar apenas o codigo? ficou um pouco confuso

Comment: @TiohStitch veja um exemplo usando o seu código https://codepen.io/AugustoVasques/pen/jOydJEE?editors=1111

Comment: eu tentei usar seu codigo mas quando eu dou reload na pagina e clico ele volta ao 1 entao n funciona

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o Local Storage

Definição pela documentação:

> A propriedade localStorage permite acessar um objeto Storage local. A localStorage é similar ao sessionStorage. A única diferença é que enquanto os dados armazenados no localStorage não expiram, os dados no sessionStorage tem os seus dados limpos ao expirar a sessão da página — ou seja, quando a página (aba ou janela) é fechada.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

- Para atribuir algum valor dentro do local storage:

```js
localStorage.setItem(nomeDoValor, valor);
```

- Para pegar algum valor dentro do local storage:

```js
const valor = localStorage.getItem(nomeDoValor);
```

- Para remover algum valor dentro do local storage:

```js
localStorage.removeItem(nomeDoValor);
```

- Para limpar todo o conteúdo do local storage:

```js
localStorage.clear();
```

* Nome do valor deve ser uma String;

** Valor também deve ser uma string, ex: Se for guardar um objeto, deve se transformar este objeto em String antes de guardar.

```js
let add = document.getElementById('increment');
let int = document.getElementById('number');

let integer;

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    integer = localStorage.getItem('pontos') || 0;
})

add.addEventListener('click', function(){
    integer += 1;
    localStorage.setItem('pontos', integer);
    int.innerHTML = integer;
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nova+Square&display=swap');
body{
    background-color: #333232;
    font-family: 'Nova Square', cursive;
}
#container{
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 10px solid #926981;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background-color: #888169;
}**

h1{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

#number{
    height: 25px;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
}

#increment{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 190px;
}
```

```html
<h1>ClickxTraffic | Earn Clicking</h1>
<div id="container">
    <div id="number">0</div>
    <button id="increment">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: ainda nao entendi

Comment: Boa resposta +1. Mas eu acho que quem o negativou(suposição minha) deve crer que no caso de um jogo os pontos devam ser salvos no back end.